# Show different pages or UI when a value is selected from dropdown?

Tags: c#, javascript, php, asp.net

I have to values in my dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Individual Form</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Entity Form</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Individual form and Entity form are two web form that have text boxes and dropdownlists. When the pages is first started or debug i want this dropdownlist to be shown and when a user selects either individual or entity the textboxes and the content of the web forms should load underneath. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cam use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Autopostback=true OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_IndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Individual Form</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Entity Form</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And take two different panel for your UI.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
 ... Your content here
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2">
 ... Your other content here
</asp:Panel>

Now in code behind write OnSelectedIndexChanged event

protected void DropDownList2_IndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  //Now check value of dropdown list and show or hide panel according to it.
  if(DropDownList2.SelectedValue=="1")
  {
    Panel1.Visible=true;
    Panel2.Visible=false;
  }
  else if(DropDownList2.SelectedValue=="2")
  {
    Panel1.Visible=false;
    Panel2.Visible=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the content underneat in an ASP:Panel with Visible set to false.  Then set the drop down to do an Autopostback=true and subscribe the the selected list item changed event,

In that event set the panel to visible = true.

If you want ajax support, put everything in an ASP:UpdatePanel.

Optionally, you could use Javascript and add an IPostBackEventHandler interface to your control/page and use __DoPostBack(ctrlId, 'somekey') to cause a postback, then in the PostBack event on IPostBackEventHandler set the panel to Visible = true.

You could also hide it with css and turn it on with javascripot but that would be superfecial and users could use web tools to turn it on themselves, e.g. hack it.

Comment: thank u for that, do u have any working examples which i can see or any other examples online if they are available?